# how do I create submenus in my module?

Tags: routes

I am pretty new to drupal php etc.

I have a module that just add links to main menu and load a .html and a .js when a link is called.

For now my menu looks like this:

- Demo

Now I would like something  like:

- Demo
- More demos

  - extra demo1
  - extra demo 2

Ideally "More demos" should be collapsed and should expand on click

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function kl_menu(){
  $items = array();


  $items['demo'] = array(
   'title'            => t('Demo'),
   'page callback'    => 'build_demo_page',
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
   'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );


  return $items;
  }


/*
 * build_demo_page
 */
function build_standard_demo_page() {
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'kl') . '/demo.js', 'file');
 return  ( file_get_contents( drupal_get_path('module', 'kl').'/demo.html') );
}
```

I am not sure to go from there.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. 
`hook_menu()` is to add new menu routers to the system. If the menu router is not defined, you will get a page not found error. 
In your case, I think you will need to add your menu items to a specific menu and add extra theming to target that menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many menu items as you need in hook_menu. Then, to have them showing in a tree, as long as the items are of type `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` you can view them in the menu admin UI, and drag & drop them in the correct order and hierarchy.

Comment: thanks that works. One little thing though is that then I need to add a content for the "more demos" link. When I click on "more demos" then that content gets displayed and the tree gets expanded. Ideally I would like that when I click on "more demos" the tree gets expanded but I would like the current page not to change (no new content). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could do that with a little bit of HTML/CSS and Javascript. If you render the whole tree at once, then hide/show some parts with javascript. You should be able to find good guides for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've pasted a sample code below. Hope that helps.

```
 function hook_menu() {
      $items = array();

      $items['demo'] = array(
      //other code here
      ); 

      $items['more-demos'] = array(
      //other code here
      );

      $items['more-demos/extra-demo-1'] = array(
      //other code here
      );

      $items['more-demos/extra-demo-2'] = array(
      //other code here
      );

      return $items;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am getting closer using your code. The subitems are displayed but when i click on the sub items I get a blank page. Then I get the message: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'build_page' not found or invalid function name in menu_execute_active_handler() (line 517 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kl-local/includes/menu.inc).

Comment: I believe you get this error because you've created only the link and not a page corresponding to that link. Create a page for each link and try again and let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved problem for me, but I think it deserves to be more elaborate. Consider editing it. I rethink it when I'm done and if you will not expand it, I'll try to do it myself.